# Javascript functions not getting called from serverside

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have 2 points from where i am calling javascript functions from server side.

```
Public Sub FNLocationName(ByVal location As String)
        System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "javascript", "SetMap('" & location & "')", True)
    End Sub


    Public Sub FNZoomLevel(ByVal IntZoomLevel As Integer)
        System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "javascript", "zoomSet('" & IntZoomLevel & "')", True)
    End Sub
```

But this is giving me error message, `undefined SetMap(locname)`

i also tried with :

```
Public Sub FNLocationName(ByVal location As String)
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "MyScript", "javascript:SetMap('" & location & "')", True)
    End Sub


    Public Sub FNZoomLevel(ByVal IntZoomLevel As Integer)
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "MyScript", "javascript:zoomSet('" & IntZoomLevel & "')", True)
    End Sub
```

But with this code, only `SetMap` function gets called, zoomset should also get called.

What can be the problem.

Please help me.

Comment: In you second sample (with `RegisterStartupScript`), give the second script a different name. Maybe `MyScript1`..?

Comment: The above user is correct. If the key names aren't unique, they will be overwritten.